# ¿Cómo subir varias imágenes a un servidor?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Trato de subir varios archivos a mi servidor local, pero llegados a la parte de PHP, parece que no le llegan los datos.

**Mi formulario:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="seleccionararchivo" name="seleccionararchivo[]" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" multiple>                        </div>
```

**Mi JavaScript:**

```
function Registrar2()
{

var archivo = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="seleccionararchivo[]"]'); //archivo[i].value

if(archivo.length==0)
{
    return Swal.fire('Mensaje De Advertencia',"Debe Seleccionar un archivo","warning");
}

var formData= new FormData();
var foto = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= archivo.length; i++) {
    foto.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="seleccionararchivo[]"]')[0].files[i]);
}

formData.append('f',foto);

$.ajax({
    url:'../Modelo/imagensubir2.php',
    type:'post',
    data:formData,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(respuesta){
        if(respuesta !=0){
            Swal.fire('Mensaje De Confirmacion',"Se subio el archivo con exito","success");
        }
    }
});
return false;
}
```

> Esta parte creo que funciona ya que, la variable "foto" antes de mandarse por Ajax, tiene los datos de las imágenes a subir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi PHP:**

```
<?php
$directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PORTALLAVEMI/images/';
if (isset($_FILES['f']))
{
    $cantidad= count($_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"]);
    
    for ($i=0; $i<=$cantidad; $i++)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"][$i],$directorio.$_FILES["f"]["name"][$i]);
        echo 1;
    }
}
else{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

> **MI PROBLEMA: No se suben las imágenes a la carpeta que asigne. ¿QUE PUEDE SER?**

Comment: El código llega a entrar en el if? En ese caso, cuanto vale $cantidad? Coincide con el número de archivos o vale 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambios a realizar:

1. En lugar de seleccionar el objeto por su input mediante **querySelectorAll** seleccionalo por su `id`, por lo tanto, cambia esto:

```javascript
var archivo = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="seleccionararchivo[]"]');
```

por esto:

```javascript
var archivo = document.getElementById('seleccionararchivo');
```

El porqué es bien sencillo. *querySelectorAll()* devuelve un array de coincidencias, que deberiamos recorrer (y que no lo estabas haciendo en tu código) para llegar a cada elemento en particular.  Como en tu código mostrado en la pregunta tan solo tienes uno, lo asignamos a una variable más facilmente con su **id**.

2. Dado este primer cambio, modifica esto tambien:

```javascript
if(archivo.length==0)
```

por esto otro:

```javascript
if (archivo.files.length == 0) {
```

De nuevo, el anterior valor de **archivo** se correspondia con la cantidad de inputs encontrados con *querySelectorAll()*, y no con la cantidad de **files** del elemento en sí, que ahora si se cumplirá correctamente la condición.

3. Elimina esta línea, ya no la vamos a necesitar:

```
var foto = [];
```

4. Eso tambien debes modificarlo:

```javascript
for (let i = 0; i <= archivo.length; i++) {
```

por esto otro:

```javascript
for (let i = 0; i < archivo.files.length; i++) {
```

por la misma regla de tres de antes. Tenias mal entendido lo que era `archivo` y además usabas el operador `<=` erroneamente en lugar del operador `<`, pues vamos a necesitar interpretar la `i` como elementos de índice, y estos empiezan por 0 en lugar de 1.

5. Cambia esta línea también:

```javascript
foto.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="seleccionararchivo[]"]')[0].files[i]);
```

por esta otra:

```javascript
formData.append('f[]', archivo.files[i]);
```

pues aquí veo que intentas crear un array en la variable **foto**, que al intentar hacer el `append` despues no va a funcionar como esperas. Es más práctico realizarlo de esta forma.

6. Elimina esta línea siguiente, ya no la vamos a necesitar:

```javascript
formData.append('f',foto);
```

Ahora vamos con el PHP:

7. Cambia esta línea:

```php
$cantidad= count($_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"]);
```

por esta otra:

```php
$cantidad = count((array)$_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"]);
```

porque así fuerzas que el valor de `$_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"]` sea tratado como **array** y se pueda contar. Eso quizás a ti no te de error, pues si usas PHP antes de la versión 7.2.0 no daba error, tal como describen en su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php), pero en mis pruebas lo he hecho con PHP 8 y he tenido que forzar ese valor.

8. Modifica esto también:

```php
for ($i=0; $i <= $cantidad; $i++) {
```

por esto:

```php
for ($i=0; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {
```

por lo mismo de antes, es decir, vamos a necesitar usar la `i` para acceder a índices que empiezan por 0, por lo tanto nunca vamos a llegar al número de elementos totales, sino al número de elementos totales menos uno.  Si lo dejas obtendrás un error al final que quizás no vas a ver, pero estará.

Con estos cambios ya deberia funcionarte "bien". Aún asi permíteme más recomendaciones:

1. En el PHP deberias verificar cada paso que haces, es decir, si el directorio existe, si los archivos son movidos, etc.
2. En el PHP deberias reservar la salida del `echo 1` o `echo 0` hasta el final del bucle, verificando si todos los archivos y pasos se han ejecutado bien primero, porque da falsos positivos y el `Swal`, tal como está ahora, puede aparecer a pesar de haber errores y no subir nada o dejarse algo.
3. La próxima vez busca ejemplos de subida multiple de archivos mediante ajax en la red, o lo que necesites, pues hay un buen puñado que funcionan y podrian haberte servido sin tener todos estos errores.

Ya nos diras si con estos cambios te funciona.  En mis pruebas locales me ha funcionado bien.